# C. Using more memory than allocated in malloc - can I return sth, end program instead of letting it crash?

Tags: c, malloc, stdin

My program crashes when `malloc(x*sizeof(char))`, `x` < limit of `fgets`, despite `buffer == NULL` check.

In my example, when x is 1, and limit of what fgets can take is 100, and user types eg. 5 characters from keyboard (fgets() call), program crashes, returning some random like: 19284791298 value.

My problem: instead of crashing, I would prefer if it returned NULL.

Reason: I upload my code to my univ's linux platform that tests program's reaction to heap limit change to 0 and to 130, when my program is written to return NULL if user's input exceeds 100 characters. I don't quite understand how the environment changes memory limit to 0 and 130 and what exactly is changed, but even though, I noticed my program in CodeBlocks, windows 10, crashes in this situation described here (x < stdin input) despite checking `buffer == NULL`.

I wish `buffer == NULL` check could somehow work and prevent the crash.

If `x` was 100, and `size` was 1 (instead of 1 and 100), my program would return NULL and set err_code to 1.

I'm thinking: I can't do with x the same "if" statement I did for strlen(buffer), because... to check how long input written to buffer is, firstly I'd need to check length of what was written to this buffer?!.

```
printf("Insert data: ");
char *buffer = (char* )malloc(1*sizeof(char));
if (buffer == NULL) 
    return NULL;

int size=100;
if (fgets(buffer, size, stdin)!=NULL) {
    if (strlen(buffer)>(unsigned)(size-2)) { //'\0' and enter are 2 chars
        free(buffer);
        *err_code=1;
        return NULL;
    }
//... here goes some sscanf to fill struct fields, etc.
}
```

In other words.
A bit condensed what I think may lead to understanding of my problem:

1. Is there a way to end program returning something, instead of letting it crash in such situation? A way to make `if(buffer == NULL)` work? Why doesn't this check work?
2. I'm unfamiliar with linux. When I see a comment in report I get, that linux sets (heap?) limit to 0 or 130 (when testing my program), does it mean I can replicate the problems it encounters by setting my `x` to `0`, `130`? (in the part `malloc(x*sizeof(char))`.

Comment: Perhaps you need [a good `fgets` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets)?

Comment: regarding: `char *buffer = (char* )malloc(1*sizeof(char));`  1) in C, the returned type from the heap allocation  functions: `malloc` `calloc` `realloc` is `void*`, which can be assigned to any pointer, Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  2) the expression: `sizeof(char)` is defined in the C standard as `1`  multiplying anything by 1 has absolutely not effect

Comment: Hmm, though when I used `sizeof buffer` instead of a certain number in   if `(fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin)!=NULL) {`, Clang reported me:
`The code calls sizeof() on a pointer type. This can produce an unexpected result`

Comment: the size parameter to `fgets()` should be the length of the receiving buffer.  Making the 'size' larger than the length of the input buffer results in undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: when using: `sizeof( buffer )` (remember that `buffer` is a pointer) the result will be the length of a pointer (depending on the underlying architecture), that could be 2 or 4 or 8 which is not what you want to pass to `fgets()`

Comment: the function: `fgets()` always appends a NUL byte to the input, so passing a buffer length of 1 will not input anything. Suggest: `char *buffer = malloc( 100 );`  However, then the code would contain some 'magic' numbers.  Suggest `#define SIZE 100`  then using `SIZE` everywhere else in the code

Answer (score 4):

When you call `fgets`, you must tell it how big the destination buffer *is*.  You are not just telling it the maximum number of characters you want it to read, so that it can automatically allocate that much space, or anything like that.  You are telling it what the size of the buffer already is, and you are telling `fgets` that it absolutely *must not* read any more characters than that, otherwise the buffer will overflow.  (`fgets` never does any allocating of its own.)

So when you say

```
char *buffer = (char* )malloc(1*sizeof(char));
```

followed by

```
int size=100;
fgets(buffer, size, stdin)
```

you have lied.  You have allocated a buffer of size 1, and you have told `fgets` that the buffer is of size 100.  So `fgets` will read up to 99 characters, and store them into `buf`, and in most cases this will badly overflow the buffer.

What you want to do is something more like this:

```
int size = 100;
char *buffer = (char* )malloc(size*sizeof(char));
if (buffer == NULL) 
    return NULL;

if (fgets(buffer, size, stdin)!=NULL) {
    ...
```

Also, although it doesn't have anything to do with your problem, there is no need to multiply by `sizeof(char)` when calling `malloc`, and in C, there is no need to cast the return from `malloc` into the destination pointer type, either.  I would just call

```
char *buffer = malloc(size);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you have allocated buffer as a single byte array

```
char *buffer = (char* )malloc(1*sizeof(char));


int size=100;
if (fgets(buffer, size, stdin)!=NULL) {
```

In the fgets, you would want to read into buffer an input of 100 bytes. When the input is read into the buffer it goes beyond the allocated area and overwrites other data. Because of this, your program crashes,